# Does Bootstrap/Django Error message has no red color?

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I wanted to play around with messages in my Django-application. Unfortunately every messagetype seems to work as expected except the error message is not red.

[image]

My Code is very simple.

views.py

```
from django.contrib import messages

def generate_test(request):
  messages.info(request, 'TEST')
  messages.success(request, 'TEST')
  messages.warning(request, 'TEST')
  messages.error(request, 'TEST')
  return render(request, 'test.html')
```

test.html

```
{% extends "base_generic3.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

My base_generic3.html contains a lot of other content like jquery and bootstrap-4 integrations. But the below part is for displaying the message in bootstrap-4 style:

```
...
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}
<div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible text-center" role="alert">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>
     <strong>{% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}Error{% else %}{{ message.tags|title }}{% endif %}!
     </strong> {{ message }}
 </div>
 {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
 ...
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue is that Django's default message tags do not match perfectly with Bootstrap's contextual classes. Bootstrap uses the contextual class `danger` for the color red. You can add the [`MESSAGE_TAGS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages/#message-tags) setting to your `settings.py` to apply the `danger` tag to messages with the level `messages.ERROR`.

> To change the default tags for a message level (either built-in or custom), set the MESSAGE_TAGS setting to a dictionary containing the levels you wish to change. As this extends the default tags, you only need to provide tags for the levels you wish to override:

**settings.py**

```
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.ERROR: 'danger',
}
```